# value of type CGSize is not contextually convertible to bool

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgsize

I'm calculating the image value of height and width and checking with if condition whether the imagsize is available or not. If not then i'm assigning some value to UIImageView size. But when i check the imagesize in if condition i got this error  `value of type CGSize is not contextually convertible to bool`

```
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(350 * widthRatio, height);

      if(imageSize){

            mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

            CGRect frame = mmageView.frame; frame.size = imageSize; mmageView.frame = frame;

        }else{

              mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your code check this way

```
if(imageSize.height != 0 && imageSize.width != 0){

   mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

   CGRect frame = mmageView.frame; frame.size = imageSize; mmageView.frame = frame;

}else{
     mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step back just a bit and think about what you're trying to do here. What condition are you trying to check? Under what cases would the size be unexpected?

`CGSize` is a struct, not an object. This means that, unlike objects, there's no way to represent this as a nil (or uninitialized) object. In your case though, it seems like what you really want to know is whether or not the size is valid. Assuming a valid size is non-zero, you can check to see whether or not the size is equal to the zero size ({0, 0}). You can do so using the `CGSizeEqualToSize` function, which returns a boolean value representing the equality of the two sizes.

Answer (score 0):

CGSize can't be a bool value. You have compare a CGSize with another CGSize.

You can use `CGSizeEqualToSize:`

```
if(CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, TheSizeYouWantToCompare))
{

}
```

Comment: you can't use CGSize as Bool value like `if(imageSize)`. The imageSize is CGSize and can't be decided it is true or false.